# InitializeComponent and map variable is throwing run time error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to integrate google maps in my xamarin form application. I have the following code on my MainPage.xaml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
                 xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
                 x:Class="App1.MainPage">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="30">

            <maps:Map WidthRequest="960" HeightRequest="700" 

           x:Name="MyMap" 

           IsShowingUser="True" 

           MapType="Street" 

           />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

and following code on my MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyMap.MoveToRegion(

           MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(

           new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(1)));
        }


    }
}
```

and following code in Mainactivity.cs file under android application:

```
 using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace App1.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

when I compile my code, it compile successfully. The whole solution compiles successfully and also the individual android project compile successfully, but when I run my code, I get the error saying

```
The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context on MainPage.xaml.cs
```

and

```
The name 'MyMap' does not exist in the current context  on MainPage.xaml.cs
```

I tried to save my MainPage.xaml page by pressing Ctrl-S

I really need help with this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: the errors you describe are compiler errors, not run-time errors.  But you say your code compiled successfully.  Are you getting errors at compile time, or exceptions/crashes at runtime?

Comment: I copied the code to another directory and somehow the errors went away. I was going to delete my post,